# SUMPRODUCT with LEN

Tags: excel

Good day! I have a table in Excel. The first line contains the norms. The rest of the lines contain days.
I need to calculate the costs by multiplying the norms by the number of days:

```
5*LEN(345) + 2*LEN(2) + 9*LEN(67) + 4*LEN(23) = 5*3 + 2*1 + 9*2 + 4*2 = 43
5*LEN(12) + 2*LEN(23) + 9*LEN(4) + 4*LEN(567) = ...
5*LEN(4) + 2*LEN(45) + 9*LEN(34) + 4*LEN(12) = ...

|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|        |    B   |    C   |    D   |  ...   |    H   |        |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|   4    |  norm  |    5   |    2   |    9   |    4   |        |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|   5    |  days  |   345  |    2   |   67   |   23   |  sum?  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|   6    |  days  |   12   |   23   |   4    |   567  |  sum?  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|   7    |  days  |   4    |   45   |   34   |   12   |  sum?  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
```

How do I write this as a formula? I tried

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C$4:H$4,C5:LEN(H5))
```

or

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(C$4:H$4,C5:LEN(H5))},
```

it doesn't work ...

Comment: 2424. I need 43.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Now it makes sense. This is the formula you need: `=SUMPRODUCT(C$4:F$4,LEN(C5:F5))`

Comment: sorry, chris neilsen answer is more accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there

try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C$4:H$4,LEN(C5:H5))
```